# Do the complete areas of various complexity classes have infinitely many problems?

Tags: computational-complexity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Complexity classes and number of problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142657/complexity-classes-and-number-of-problems)

I know that almost all of complexity classes that have some significance have infinite number of decision problems.

Then what about complete area of these complexity classes? I know that the concept of complete is somewhat artificial, as it depends on some reduction processes.

So, for example, will NP-complete contain infinite number of problems?

Thanks.

Comment: There are certainly infinitely many NP-complete problems; for example, determining whether a graph is $k$-colorable is NP-complete for any $k \geq 3$. I suspect that you could come up with similarly trivial examples for just about any complexity class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of $\mathcal{NP}$-complete problems is infinite, as are all the complexity classes that are interesting, because for any finite "complexity class" $\mathcal C$, there is an algorithm to solve problems from $\mathcal C$ in constant time.